# How to byte-swap a 32-bit integer in python?

Tags: python, integer, endianness

Take this example:

```
i = 0x12345678
print("{:08x}".format(i))
   # shows 12345678
i = swap32(i)
print("{:08x}".format(i))
   # should print 78563412
```

What would be the `swap32-function()`? Is there a way to byte-swap an `int` in python, ideally with built-in tools?

Comment: Alternatively, the [`array.byteswap()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) method if you first convert the number into a byte-array

Comment: @aruisdante I found this question, but its title does not correspond to what is asked by the OP.... changed its title.

Comment: Your example is swapping the order of 4-bit chunks, not bytes. If you swapped the order of the four bytes, `{ 12 34 56 78 }`, it would be `{ 78 56 34 12 }`.

Comment: @AaronF what? Your "it would be" is exactly what I put in the comment.

Comment: My bad. I misread it has 87654321. Sorry about that. You're right.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One method is to use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module:

```
def swap32(i):
    return struct.unpack("<I", struct.pack(">I", i))[0]
```

First you pack your integer into a binary format using one endianness, then you unpack it using the other (it doesn't even matter which combination you use, since all you want to do is swap endianness).

Comment: What should be the result of swap32(12345678) ?

Comment: @AerofoilKite be careful, don't be confused by the print of `{:08x}`, it is omitting the `0x`. 12345678 != 0x12345678

Comment: @Carsten, "i" format for functions pack and unpack means signed integer. As a result, value like 0x87654321 is not handled well with your definition. To treat values as unsigned, format "I" could be used: `struct.unpack("<I", struct.pack(">I", i))[0]`

Comment: @ArtemZankovich Thank you! I forgot about that. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 31):

Big endian means the layout of a 32 bit int has the most significant byte first,

e.g. 0x12345678 has the memory layout

```
msb             lsb
+------------------+
| 12 | 34 | 56 | 78|
+------------------+
```

while on little endian, the memory layout is

```
lsb             msb
+------------------+
| 78 | 56 | 34 | 12|
+------------------+
```

So you can just convert between them with some bit masking and shifting:

```
def swap32(x):
    return (((x << 24) & 0xFF000000) |
            ((x <<  8) & 0x00FF0000) |
            ((x >>  8) & 0x0000FF00) |
            ((x >> 24) & 0x000000FF))
```

Comment: I will do like this, but it is not used a "built-in" functionality as I asked for. Which is why I accept the other answer.

Comment: Bitwise shift, OR, and AND are about as "built-in" as it gets.

Answer (score 18):

From python 3.2 you can define function swap32() as the following:

```
def swap32(x):
    return int.from_bytes(x.to_bytes(4, byteorder='little'), byteorder='big', signed=False)
```

It uses array of bytes to represent the value and reverses order of bytes by changing endianness during conversion back to integer.

Comment: Nice! Also can be easily modified for 64-bit integers.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe simpler use the socket library.

```
from socket import htonl

swapped = htonl (i)
print (hex(swapped))
```

that's it.
this library also works in the other direction with ntohl

Comment: Err, this won't work on big-endian systems.  That's the whole point of htonl.

Answer (score 1):

The [array](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/array.html) module provides a [byteswap()](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/array.html#array.array.byteswap) method for fixed sized items.
The array module appears to be in versions back to Python 2.7

> array.byteswap()
> “Byteswap” all items of the array. This is only supported for values which are 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes in size;

Along with the [fromfile()](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/array.html#array.array.fromfile) and [tofile()](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/array.html#array.array.tofile) methods, this module is quite easy to use:

```
import array

# Open a data file.
input_file = open( 'my_data_file.bin' , 'rb' )

# Create an empty array of unsigned 4-byte integers.
all_data = array.array( 'L' )

# Read all the data from the file.
all_data.fromfile( input_file , 16000 )               # assumes the size of the file

# Swap the bytes in all the data items.
all_data.byteswap( )

# Write all the data to a new file.
output_file = open( filename[:-4] + '.new' , 'wb' )    # assumes a three letter extension
all_data.tofile( output_file )

# Close the files.
input_file.close( )
output_file_close( )
```

The above code worked for me since I have fixed-size data files. There are more Pythonic ways to handle variable length files.