# Endianess - hex to dec little endian. uncorrect data types

Tags: python, endianness

I converted hex to dec, but it turned out to be in big endian and I need little endian (ex. 1500 = 21 instead 5376 which I get). I tried to use struct function but I get some problem:

```
u16ModuleID_hex = str(f3.read(4))
ba = bytearray.fromhex(u16ModuleID_hex)
ba.reverse()
u16ModuleID_dec = struct.unpack("<h", ba)
```

Error: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 1
So, I added: `ba = bytearray.fromhex(u16ModuleID_hex[0][2:])`
Error: struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 2 bytes

u16ModuleID_hex is for example b'10b5'. I assume it's sth with the b' in front and overall with data types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to byte-swap a 32-bit integer in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506474/how-to-byte-swap-a-32-bit-integer-in-python)

Comment: not really :/ Maybe I could try to convert int from big endian to little?

Answer (score 2):

*need little endian (ex. 1500 = 21 instead 5376 which I get)*

Take look at [`int.frombytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) (requires `python3.2` or newer)

```
data = b'\x15\x00'
print(int.from_bytes(data, "big"))
print(int.from_bytes(data, "little"))
```

output

```
5376
21
```

Comment: How to get data in that format? I just have 1500 as my data

Comment: @immonual: As your data seems to be of type `bytes` you should be able to apply this approach. The way `data` is defined here is to ensure a `bytes` variable.

Comment: @immonual assuming `f3` is file handle opened in read-binary (`"rb"`) mode or any other device which emits bytes when `.read` then do `int.from_bytes(f3.read(4))`

Comment: TypeError: from_bytes() missing required argument 'byteorder' (pos 2)

Comment: @immonaul Right, I forgot byteorder, so `int.from_bytes(f3.read(4),"little")`

Comment: u16ModuleID_hex = int.from_bytes(f3.read(4),"little")
u16ModuleID_dec = int.from_bytes(u16ModuleID_hex, "little")
TypeError: cannot convert 'int' object to bytes

Comment: @immonual `int.from_bytes(f3.read(4),"little")` does return `int` (integer), you should use `int.from_bytes` once not twice

Comment: u16ModuleID_hex = f3.read(4)
u16ModuleID_dec = int.from_bytes(u16ModuleID_hex, "little")                                                  If I leave it like that i get the following result:  b'10b5' = 895627313

Comment: @immonual how many *bytes* have your number? `10b5` suggest 2 bytes, so you should `.read(2)` rather than `.read(4)`

Comment: i read it sign by sign, so 4 chars

Comment: @immonual if you have 4 chars, `10b5` then do `int(b'10b5'[::-1].decode('ascii'),16)` if your desired output is `23297`

Comment: 46352 is the one

Comment: for 1500 i got 81 and 1500 in little endian is 21

Comment: u16ModuleID_hex = str(f3.read(4))
ba = bytearray.fromhex(u16ModuleID_hex[2:-1])
ba.reverse()
u16ModuleID_dec = ''.join(format(x, '02x') for x in ba)
u16ModuleID_dec = u16ModuleID_dec.upper()
u16ModuleID_dec = int(u16ModuleID_dec, 16)

Comment: works that way, if you are interested :) Thank you for your help though

Answer (score 1):

Just [`.pack()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack) and [`.unpack()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) your data to flip endianess:

```
import struct

a = 0x1500

print(a)
# --> 5376

b, = struct.unpack("<h", struct.pack(">h", a))
print(b)
# --> 21
```

Comment: my a  is equal to 1500 not 0x1500

Comment: struct.error: 'h' format requires -32768 <= number <= 32767

Comment: `0x` is to ensure hex notation for an integer upon variable definition/declaration.

Comment: I know, but how to add it then?

Comment: Please elaborate on your exact data types in your question for further debugging. Some data conversion might not be correct in your original code.

Comment: (variable) u16ModuleID_hex: bytes